# Strange, double click/mouse dragging will trigger key event "CTRL-C"

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

Qt seems to behavior strangely: when mouse double click or dragging on a widget, it will trigger the Ctrl-C key event. Here is my code:

```
class CWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    CWidget()
    {

    };
    virtual ~CWidget()
    {
    }

protected:
    void keyPressEvent ( QKeyEvent * event ) 
    {
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key_C && (event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier))
        {
            qDebug() << "strange copy: Ctrl-C";
        }
        QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
    }
}; //
```

After the widget is shown, you can perform mouse double click and dragging around on it, and the debug message "strange copy:Ctrl-C" is printed. I have been searching over the internet for two days about this, and found nothing.

Did I use it wrong or it is a bug of Qt?

The code is tested under (vs2008 + Qt Addin + Qt 4.7.3) and (qcreator + Qt 4.7.3 ), xp sp2

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem and finally figured out why. It is caused by using translating software, such as "有道词典".

When you double click or drag, it is likely to pick up some text in the text area, and the translating software is hijacking that action by some means, and automatically triggering a copy action intending to get the picked text to translate it automatically. This caused this strange behaviour.

This is unlikely to happen on English users, and unlikely to reproduce the problem, if translating software was not open.

Comment: this solves my problem. I removed this shit dictionary software.

Answer (score 0):

You must check:

```
!event->isAutoRepeat();
```